# Color gradient to unfoldingmap in Processing

Tags: processing

can you please tell me how i can change the color gradient in the following piece of code? In my code im trying to control the color gradient from here:

```
for( Marker marker : countryMarkers ) {
    for( i=0; i<255; i++ ){
        marker.setColor(color(255, i, 0));    
    }
}
```

Unfortunately im getting one color only. Can you help please?

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.tiles.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.interactions.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.ui.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.core.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.shaders.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.texture.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.events.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.utils.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.*;
import java.util.List;
UnfoldingMap map;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);

int i=0,k=15;

  map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Microsoft.AerialProvider());
  Location cyprusLocation = new Location(35f, 33f);
  map.zoomAndPanTo(cyprusLocation, 11);
  float maxPanningDistance = 30; // in km
  map.setPanningRestriction(cyprusLocation, maxPanningDistance);
  //map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);

  List<Feature> countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "Dasos.geo.json");
  List<Marker> countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
  map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);
  /*
  for (Marker marker : countryMarkers) {
 // marker.setColor(color(255, 0, 0));

}
*/
  for (Marker marker : countryMarkers) {
for(i=0;i<255;i++){
marker.setColor(color(255, i, 0));


}
  }

}

void draw() {
  map.draw();
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    map.getDefaultMarkerManager().toggleDrawing();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a nested loop, so you are setting each marker with every color, from (255, 0 ,0) until (255, 255, 0), before displaying it. At the end they are all left with the same last color in the inner loop...

You might just use a regular `for` loop to traverse the array, so you can use the index as part of color(). But you need to mind somehow the maximum numbers, something like:

(note you were missing the `int` inside regular for loop)

```java
for(int i = 0; i < countryMarkers.length; i++){

  countryMarkers[i].setColor(color(255, (i%255), 0));    
}
```

or just use an incremented var inside the `for each` instead the index...

```java
for (Marker marker : countryMarkers) {

  marker.setColor(color(255, (otherVar++)%255, 0));
   }
```